# How to properly generate self signed certificates for use in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, curl

I used openssl to generate the following certificates:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj "/C=IT/ST=Mi/L=Milan/O=MyOrg/OU=RnD/CN=localhost/emailAddress=info@myorg.com"
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.insicure.key
cat server.insicure.key > certificate.pem
cat server.crt >> certificate.pem
```

I then setup nginx to client-secure a site:

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    root /var/www/site;

    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate         /root/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /root/server.key;

    ssl_client_certificate  /root/certificate.pem;

    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;

     location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to get the site with curl, it doesn't work as expected:

```
curl --cacert certificate.pem https://localhost:80
```

and I get the following error page from nginx:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are instructing Nginx to request a client certificate with:

```
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

However, you've not told `curl` to use one (`--cacert` only tells `curl` where the CA certificate to use to verify the server certificate is located).  Nginx therefore correctly tells you that you haven't sent a client certificate.

If you only want the server to send a TLS certificate in order to get HTTPS working then simply comment out or remove the two lines above.

If you do want the client to send a certificate, then you should create a CA and use it to issue a client certificate.  Give the client certificate and private key to `curl` (use `--cert` and `--key` respectively) and configure the CA certificate in Nginx with `ssl_client_certificate` (without the private key!!).

This [question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/168580/creating-client-certificates) shows how to create a client certificate using OpenSSL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. What do you mean I'm not telling curl to use a certificate? Isn't it what "--cacert certificate.pem" is about? If this is incorrect, how do I "create a CA and use it to issue a client certificate"? Thanks